# Exporting ArcGIS plugin data source to Shape?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I have implemented a plug-in data source for ArcGIS. In my case, the format read by the plug-in may contain point, line and polygon features within the same file. 
In my implementation the data file read by the plugin is a dataset which may contain up to three feature classes (point, line, poly).

In ArcMap I can sucessfully browse to my data sources and add feature classes to the map. If I then open the **ArcToolbox->Conversion Tools->To Shapefile->Feature Class To Shape** tool I can see the added feature classes in the **Input Features** pulldown menu and add them. Using this method I can sucessfully export the feature class to a Shape file.

Also, in ArcCatalog I can browse to the feature classes contained in my custom files or I can enter a path into the **Location:** box in ArcCatalog for example: **f:\arctest\plugindata\testPT\testPT_PT** where **f:\arctest\plugindata** is the location of my data file, **testPT** is the root name of my data file (less extenstion) and **testPT_PT** is the name of the feature class within the file. Doing this will sucessfully browse to and open my file.

The trouble coumes when I attempt to use the **ArcToolbox->Conversion Tools->To Shapefile->Feature Class To Shape** tool and enter the full path to my feature class **f:\arctest\plugindata\testPT\testPT_PT** directly into the **Input Features** box rather than first adding the feature class to a map and then selecting it via the **Input Features** dialog. I am immediately greeted with 000732 dataset does not exist or is not supported.

I believe that I have traced the probem to the call made by ArcGIS to the [ContainsWorkspace()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000684000000) that I have implemented in my custom workspace factory. My ContainsWorkspace() is being called and the parentDirectory being passed to me in the above example is **f:\arctest** when I expect to be called with **f:\arctest\plugindata**. As it is I am being called to indicate whether **f:\arctest** contains a workspace which it does not, **f:\arctest\plugindata** does. ContainsWorkspace() is never called with **f:\arctest\plugindata** and the Export To Shape tool immediately indicates that the specified feature class is invalid.

Again, if I enter **f:\arctest\plugindata\testPT\testPT_PT** into the location box in ArcCatalog I am immediately taken to the correct featureclass, it is only the Shape Export dialog that will not accept this path.

I am fairly new to ArcGIS Engine development and this is my first data source plugin so I I have not clearly explained the situation I apologize.

Can anyone give me some pointers on where to look for my failure?

Comment: Is the IFileNames arg for ContainsWorkspace null?  If not what does it contain?

Comment: When coming from GP tools, the workspace name will be the full path to the file. The IFileNames object will be null.

Comment: Have you tried running the `MakeFeatureLayer` tool on your custom feature class first?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think some ESRI tools work only with ArcObject supported datasources(Shape,Coverage,Personal GDB,SDE GDB),maybe you have selected a tool which expect an ArcObject datasource as input?

I have a similar problem with OLEDB datasource which I have developed,some ArcMap features specially Editor objects doesn't work with it.

Comment: This is stated in the plugin datasource documentation: "The following are some limitations to plug-in data sources—only tables, feature classes, and feature datasets are supported. Plug-in data sources cannot be integrated with geodatabase objects, such as relationship classes and geometric networks. Also, only simple feature types—points, lines, and polygons—are supported. For example, plug-in data sources for annotation or dimension features cannot be implemented." http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Plug_in_data_sources/000100000003000000/

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure this is an ArcGIS bug. Just report it and wait for the SP :)